# Expand divs with jquery and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code to display one div when I click a link:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.expand-one').click(function(){
        $('.content-one').slideToggle('fast');
    });
})
```

But the problem here is that I have a lot of divs and links. How to tell jquery to search its corresponding div? When I click `<a href="#" class="expand-**one**"></a>` it expands by itself `<div class="content-**one**">`, and when I click another link it closes the open one and opens its corresponding div. I want to do this without having to do this for each link (two, three, etc.).

Here is my full code

http://jsfiddle.net/4on1exz5/

Comment: you can use the split function.. post your html

Comment: Can you post your sample html showing how your `a` and `div` elements are placed ? Once we know how they're arranged, we can try and answer your question :)

Comment: You probably mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mLf8zgzL/ ... but it's better to post complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help you?

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="expandcommand" id="expandcommand-1">Open 1</a>
<div class="contentexpand" id="contentexpand-2">Hello 2</div>
<a href="#" class="expandcommand" id="expandcommand-2">Open 2</a>
<div class="contentexpand" id="contentexpand-1">Hello 1</div>
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('div').hide();
    $('.expandcommand').on('click', function() {
        var contentcontainerid= getContentid($(this).attr('id'));

        $('#' + contentcontainerid).slideToggle('fast');

        function getContentid(expandcommandid) {
            var arrayattr= expandcommandid.split('-');
            return 'contentexpand-' + arrayattr[arrayattr.length - 1];
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jcghdLt1/2/

Comment: This is exactly what i want but how do i close the others? for example if i click Open 3 the content of open 1 remains open but i need to close before the new one opens https://jsfiddle.net/jcghdLt1/3/

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm gonna make this simple, if all your anchor tags have common `expand` class and all your `div` elements have common `content` class and they're placed one below the other like this

```
<a href="#" class="expand">Open 1</a>
<div class="content">Hello</div>
```

Assuming your `content` class will have rules in CSS file to hide that div or you can have an inline `style="display:none;"` on the div element, then on click of hyper link, you can select the next div element and toggle it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $div = $(this).next('.content');
        $('.content').not($div).slideUp('slow');
        $div.slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/6tsp8hz2/)

html

```
<div class="expand-one expand" data-target=".content-one">expand one</div>
<div class="expand-two expand" data-target=".content-two">expand two</div>
<div class="expand-three expand" data-target=".content-three">expand three</div>
<div class="expand-four expand" data-target=".content-four">expand four</div>

<div class="content-one">one</div>
<div class="content-two">two</div>
<div class="content-three">three</div>
<div class="content-four">four</div>
```

css

```
.content-one, .content-two, .content-three, .content-four {
    display:none;
    background:red;
}
```

jquery

```
$(".expand").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).data("target"); 
     $(target).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to the `<a>` click event like so:

```js
$(function () {

    $('a').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == "#") {
            e.preventDefault();
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            var contentClass = className.replace("expand-", ".content-");
            var exists = $(contentClass).length;
          
            if (exists == 1) { $(contentClass).slideToggle('fast'); }
            
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.content-one {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
    display: none;
}
.content-two {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="expand-one">Expand 1</a>
<div class="content-one">Content One</div>
<br>
    
<a href="#" class="expand-two">Expand 2</a>
<div class="content-two">Content Two</div>
<br>
    
<a href="www.google.com">A real link<a/>
```

This way, you won't have to bind to each `.expand` element's click event, and you still retain usage of your hyperlinks. The stipulation is that all of your expandable links will have `href="#"` and a corresponding `.content` div -- which I think is in line with your request.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery also provides way more selectors that perhaps you will find useful.  I would look into ID selectors or something a little more definitive than just a class selector.  At a minimum you can use a little more context for your selector - so if each link and div are contained within the same parent div, which is different from other link/div combos, you can use a "sibling" selector and get closer that way.  Your problem is that the class selector gets ALL of the elements with that class unless you narrow it down a bit.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: anybody care to explain the downvote?  I guess I didn't figure this one required a full-blown example when reading the documentation would probably suffice.